# Creating html parser, wrong condition in Java

Tags: java, html-parsing, bufferedreader

newbie here. I'm trying to create a very simple html parser.
In this parser I make the assumption that each tag is in its own line and the tags don not include additional information (like color).
So far I have created two classes: One which includes the main method(mainClass) and another one whose object is called when the `<body>` tag is called. The body class has a method called "toPrint" that prints whatever is included inside the tags `<body>`, `</body>` (or at least that's what I hoped.)
I use a bufferedreader to read the file line by line, and I want to stop the reading once the `</body>` is read, but buffferedReader still continues to print.

MainClass

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Html.txt"))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            switch(line.trim()) {
                case "<html>" :
                    break;
                case "</html>" :
                    break;
                case "<body>" :
                    (new Body(br)).toPrint();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println(line);
            }                                               //end of try//
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Body

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Body {

private final BufferedReader br;

public Body(BufferedReader br) {
    this.br = br;
}

public void toPrint() {

    String line;

    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            if (line.trim() != "</body>") {             //I think the problem is here
                System.out.println(line.trim());

            } else {
                break;                                    //breaks while loop
            }


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The file I read

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: learn how to compare Strings. if (line.trim() != "</body>") is indeed the problem, you should 've used the equals method instead of !=

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. You are using `!=` operator to compare string. I would suggest you use `!"</body>".equals(line)`
2. I would suggest you use equalsIgnoreCase for the comparison of string, so even if i have `</Body>` as tag, it would still match the tag and would break. Similarly in your switch, you could do `switch (line.toLowerCase().trim())`